# How to run a moderated multilevel mediation in R?

Tags: r, interaction, multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

I am trying to run a *moderated* multilevel mediation in R. I have encountered the mlma and bmlm packages, as well as Elizabeth Page-Gould's open-source code for testing indirect effects in multi-level data. All of this has been useful but does not have the additional functionality to test for moderation in a multilevel mediation.

I am examining trials within participants, and looking at how a fourth variable may be moderating the indirect effect. All variables are level 1 variables.

Is there a best way to go about executing a moderated multilevel mediation in R? Or will I most likely have to go to MPlus in order to execute something like this?