# How to perform multilevel moderated mediation analysis with {mediate}

Tags: r, interaction, multilevel-analysis, mediation

I'm attempted to run a multilevel moderated mediation analysis in R using the `mediate` package. Some details on my sample:

- I have an experimentally manipulated variable (X), which I expect to causally effect a measured variable (M).
- The effect of X on M depends on a moderator (W), which is a personality measure
- I then expect my measured variable (M) to have a positive relationship to an outcome variable (Y)
- One covariate that I want to control for

See below for a visual description of the relationship between these variables.

[image]

So far, this would be very easy to estimate using the `mediation` package, or Andrew Hayes' PROCESS model 7. However, the study I ran was a within-subjects study wherein participants saw the manipulated stimuli X and completed measures of M and Y on 7 separate occasions.

My understanding is that this requires a multilevel model, using participants ID as a grouping variable. I've therefore used the following code to construct a `mediate` object:

```r
model.in <- lmer(M ~ X * W + Covariate +
       (1 | ID),
     data = clean_data)

model.out <- lmer(Y ~ M + X + Covariate + W +
       (1 | ID),
     data = clean_data) 

med.out <- mediate(model.in, model.out, treat = "X", mediator = "M",  sims = 10000)
```

This returns a normal causal mediation object that works as expected. However, when I try to run `test.modmed()`, using the lowest and highest levels of my moderator variable, I get an error:

```r
test.modmed(med.out, list("W" = 1),
            list("W"  = 5), sims = 100)

# Error message: Error in test.modmed.default(med.out, 
# list(AggressiveHumour = 1, AggressiveHumour = 5), 
# :currently no test.modmed method exists for the input object.
```

My questions are:

1. Have I done something wrong here, or is this just a limitation of `mediate`?
2. If it's the latter, what's a good alternative?

I've found this question asked before, but left unanswered: [How to run a moderated multilevel mediation in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432455/how-to-run-a-moderated-multilevel-mediation-in-r)

Comment: Did you see this? It has nice examples of which types of moderated mediation tests you can and cannot do in `mediate` and shows how you could use `lavaan` for this if you wanted to. https://ademos.people.uic.edu/Chapter15.html#4_moderated_mediation_analyses_using_%E2%80%9Cmediation%E2%80%9D_package